# Change color of curently evaluating cell using stylesheets

Tags: stylesheet

How can I change the format of the cell, which is currently being evaluated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possibility is to use [`CellProlog`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CellProlog)/[`CellEpilog`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CellEpilog):

```
SetOptions[
    EvaluationNotebook[],
    StyleDefinitions -> Notebook[
        {
        Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions->"Default.nb"]],
        Cell[StyleData["Input"],
            CellProlog:>SetOptions[EvaluationCell[], Background->RGBColor[1,0,0]],
            CellEpilog:>SetOptions[EvaluationCell[], Background->None]
        ]
        },
        StyleDefinitions->"PrivateStylesheetFormatting.nb"
    ]
]
```